# Camel transaction demarcation

Tags: java, spring, transactions, apache-camel, spring-transactions

I have the following route:

```
from("jms:some-queue")  
  .transacted("txPolicy")       
    .beanRef("bean1", "method1")
    .beanRef("bean2", "method2")
    .beanRef("bean3", "method3")
    .beanRef("bean4", "method4")
```

I would like to have  `beanRef("bean4", "method4")`to run outside the transaction. Any suggestions to implement this within camel route?

I'm aware it is possible to mark the individual beans as @Transactional but I'd prefer not to change the beans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 2 routes and link them with [direct](http://camel.apache.org/direct.html):

```
from("jms:some-queue")  
  .transacted("txPolicy")       
    .beanRef("bean1", "method1")
    .beanRef("bean2", "method2")
    .beanRef("bean3", "method3")
    .to("direct:bean4.method4")

from("direct:bean4.method4")
    .beanRef("bean4", "method4")
```

**Edit**: realized that this does not address

> Any suggestions to implement **this withing camel route?**

Comment: thanks, if it's not possible to demarcate within the route then I'll look into creating a separate one as above.